# In JavaScript var x=2, var y="2"; console.log(x-y), why is o/p 0?

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

Will Programmers help me to find the logic behind this x-y o/p 0????
`

```
var a=3;
  var b="3";
  console.log(a+b); //o/p is 33
  var x=2;
  var y="2"; 
  console.log(x-y); //o/p is 0
```

`

Comment: `+` while a math operator it is also a string concatenation operator hence you get a string concatenation instead of a math operation. `-` on the other hand only acts as a math operator

Comment: but we define the value of y in string form....

Comment: Yes, but `-` convert every params to `Number`

Comment: kk. Thankyou Patrick Evans & @FahDev.

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick has mentioned, At this level, + operator's behaviour is dependent on the type of operands supplied to it, i.e it'll either do concatenation or addition( for no's )

In subtraction, JS is casting the string operand for appropriate subtraction. Find more here about [addition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment)

So you can just say: "This is how it works"

Answer (score 0):

In javascript + is also used for strings.
For example ("My age:"+21)===>My age:21
When you plus string and number,it will be seen like the example.
But when you use -  it will work just as mathematic operator. This is javascript